# Can't activate proprietary driver for NVIDIA from "Additional drivers" Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, proprietary

Can't activate proprietary driver for NVIDIA from "Additional drivers" Ubuntu 14.04

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04,64 bit, with nvidia 610M dedicated graphics card.

By default when I go to "Softwares & Updates" > "Additional Drivers" it shows "Using X.Org X server-Nouveau display driver..." selected.

But I wanted to switch to proprietary nvidia driver so I selected "Using NVIDIA binary driver-version 331.38..." and clicked "Apply Changes" but shows a progress bar and after few seconds the "Nouveau" driver again shows selected.

I gave `apt-get update` from the terminal.
Did a reboot after "Apply Changes"
But still no luck.

[image: It shows Nouveau driver ever after "Apply changes" and Reboot]

Comment: What does `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331` say?

Comment: It listed out a bunch of packages for installation including nvidia. So why does it didn't get install when "Apply Changes" are clicked

Comment: Presumably some error occurs and it rolls back. Did you let the `apt-get install` run to completion?

Comment: Same issue as you Nikhil. Did you resolve?

Comment: Did you try from a terminal the sudo apt-get --reinstall install nvidia-331 and look for errors.?  I've had the "additional drivers" selection fail to completely build all the modules.

Comment: I was having this same issue in **March 2020** ! It turns out that it just **seems** that you can't select it, but if you wait for 2-3 minutes, the selection happens.
It's just a design-fault, they didn't make it so that you know something is happening in the background!

Answer (score 9):

You can run this action from command line, using utility `ubuntu-drivers`. In this case you will get some helpful descriptions of error. To install the most appropriate version use `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Answer (score 6):

Under "Ubuntu Software" in the Software & Updates page set the `Download From` to be "Main Server"

This then lets you install the drivers...

[image]

You can then Install the Drivers for the Nvidia

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and the

```
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

gave me some errors so I had to revome all the nvidia libs with the following commands

```
 sudo apt remove cuda
 sudo apt remove "nvidia*"
 sudo apt autoremove
```

and then I did as @Barafu Albino suggested.

Comment: Apart from cuda not being installed, this is what worked for me to get at lease decent resolution back, and allowing me to choose between drivers (I'm leaving them alone and not touching them now that they work on default "Using NVidia driver metapackage from nvidia-packag-390" (proprietary, tested))