# CSGO Running slow in ubuntu help

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, framerate

Hello i just recently dual booted my computer ubuntu and windows.Windows is just fine but i just wanted to dual boot and see the CSGO in linux but i get around 40 30 FPS in game with lowest settings in Windows CSGO Max settings around 100 fps anybody can know a fix i have nvidia 640

Comment: Are you using the Nvidia proprietary drivers. If not, you may get vetter performance by installing them from "Additional drivers".

Comment: There is no propretary drivers everything is open source in nvidia but in intel Using Procceser Code or something like that is elected (it is a propretary driver)

Comment: Is there an option to install drivers for the nvidia card (see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/540862/cant-activate-proprietary-driver-for-nvidia-from-additional-drivers-ubuntu-14) ? The open source nouveau driver sometimes does not give the best possible performance for games

Comment: like what sudo apt-get install nvidia-331

Comment: or main server thingy

Comment: i dont understand i think the nvidia drivers are not installed likem mesa or something like that

Comment: When you go in "Software and updates", and then on the " Additional drivers" tab, you should be able to just choose nvidia-331, click "Apply", and done. Does that not work ?

Comment: "Software and updates" opens and immediatly closes i dont know how to type BAD ENGLISH

Comment: http://i66.tinypic.com/1h9hm9.png

Comment: JonasCZ there is no nvidia 331