# There is no Nvidia proprietary driver in Additional Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, additional-drivers

In my recent question I didn't get the meaning of Nvidia proprietary driver. Can somebody help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a good question because you are using the NVIDIA binary driver version 340.102 (open source) and I am using the NVIDIA binary driver version 340.101 (proprietary, tested) from the default Ubuntu repositories and I would also like to know the answer to this question.

Comment: did you see my screenshot

Comment: and my http://askubuntu.com/questions/891946/csgo-running-slow-in-ubuntu-help post

Comment: if yes what should i do

Comment: I noticed something else that's different in your screenshot it says you are using an alternative driver and in my Additional Drivers tab it says I am using the recommended driver. I installed my driver from the terminal with the command: `sudo apt install nvidia-340` How did you install your Nvidia driver?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/301648/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu

Comment: [SS](http://tinypic.com/r/52ibdj/9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `nvidia-xxx` are proprietary Nvidia drivers.

They are shown as "open source" because you added an unofficial PPA, probably `graphics-drivers/ppa` and the system can't detect what driver is there.

You can check the `nvidia-375`. It should support your GT 640.

Comment: what do i have to do

Comment: You have do nothing. Proprietary drivers are installed.

Comment: why am i getting low fps in csgo then in LOWEST settings in LINUX but in WINDOWS its 100 max set

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? The driver looks to be wrong for your card.

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Try the 375 version. It is unofficial, but it should support your card.

Comment: GTX 640 Nvidia ?

Comment: so how i a i going to install that ppa or what

Comment: You have GT 640. The PPA is already installed. Select the 375 driver and press "Apply changes".

Comment: should i restart my computer now

Comment: Yes, but first find out how to remove these drivers from console is something goes wrong.

Comment: sudo apt remove or what

Comment: i installed with these commands sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates sudo nvidia-xconfig so i should use sudo apt remove RIGHT?

Comment: NM i just f it !