# Additional drivers are disabled

Tags: nvidia

Actually I want to activate driver of NVIDIA but it seems to be blocked.

[image]

What can I do for that?

Comment: See if this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/540862/cant-activate-proprietary-driver-for-nvidia-from-additional-drivers-ubuntu-14

Comment: @pomsky actually I also probe it but it doesn't work . In Additional drivers it doesn't let me choose any option above.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but putting a potential solution here just in case someone needs it. From terminal run:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-384
```

Next time it should show you that it is using that driver.