# Can't Change To Nvidia Proprietary Driver Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I recently upgraded to 18.04 from 16.04. My machine has NVIDIA Graphics cards 
Quadro 410 When i tried to change graphics driver using the GUI mode under Software and updates. The default X.Org X server keeps on getting selected and I do not get any error.

I see two additional Drivers listed besides the one selected by default

1. nvidia-driver-390
2. nvidia-driver-340
3. X org driver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540862/cant-activate-proprietary-driver-for-nvidia-from-additional-drivers-ubuntu-14?rq=1)

Comment: What are the results of running `ubuntu-drivers devices` ? iinm the results of `ubuntu-drivers devices` recommend installing nvidia-driver-390 with `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390 && sudo reboot` This is basically the same as what singrium's answer says.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to remove the installed drivers by running:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo apt remove nvidia-*  
sudo apt autoremove
```

Check what is the recommended driver for your Nvidia card by running:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

If you want to install the driver automatically, run :

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

If you want to install a specific driver, run:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-<driver number>
```

Once the installation is finished, run `prime-select query` to check which graphic card is being used by your device.
If you want to change the graphic card used by your PC, run : `sudo prime-select <intel/ nvidia>`; choose between Nvidia and Intel graphic cards.
After that, restart your PC to apply changes