# Installation of NVDIA drivers on ASUS Zenbook14 - Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, asus

I am trying to install latest NVDIA graphics drivers on the ASUS zenbook 14, running Ubuntu 19.04. I am following this tutorial: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/

According to the window of the software updater, the driver is there:

[image]

But when I am checking the status of the driver, I get:

```
giulio@giulio-ZenBook-UX431FN:~$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

PS. Grub is on `nomodeset`.

How can I get the driver installed?

I am posting the edit of the following commands:

```
giulio@giulio-ZenBook-UX431FN:~$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
[sudo] password for giulio: 
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001D12sv00001043sd00001EBEbc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP108M [GeForce MX150]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin


giulio@giulio-ZenBook-UX431FN:~$ mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot enabled

giulio@giulio-ZenBook-UX431FN:~$ test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo "Legacy(bios)"
efi

giulio@giulio-ZenBook-UX431FN:~$ sudo lshw -c video 
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:6012000000-6012ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP108M [GeForce MX150]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff memory:80000000-80ffffff memory:6000000000-600fffffff memory:6010000000-6011ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:81000000-8107ffff


giulio@giulio-ZenBook-UX431FN:~$  dkms status
nvidia, 418.56, 5.0.0-13-generic, x86_64: installed


giulio@giulio-ZenBook-UX431FN:~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11

giulio@giulio-ZenBook-UX431FN:~$ lspci -knn | grep -A 3 -E "(VGA|3D)"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) [8086:3ea0]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) [1043:1ebe]
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 0b)
--
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] [10de:1d12] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP108M [GeForce MX150] [1043:1ebe]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Sandisk Corp Device [15b7:5003] (rev 01)
```

`lsmod | grep nvidia` gives no output.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI settings.

Comment: And, **of course** remove the `nomodeset` parameter.

Comment: Apparently, it not solved my issue. Using insecure boot + quiet-splash instead of nomeodeset bring me to the old blank screen issue, despite the driver apparently installed. Running with the insecure boot and with nomodeset has another problem: basically the system starts with a 4:3 screen instead of 16:9 and it blocks on a black screen with only a white underscore sign at upper left corner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Shall I try this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/is-a-nvidia-geforce-with-optimus-technology-supported-by-ubuntu

Comment: Is there a way to have an external monitor working while using nomodeset?

Comment: Please edit your question and post  output of the following commands: 1. `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` 2. `mokutil --sb-state` 3. `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo "Legacy(bios)"` 4. `sudo lshw -c video`  5. `dkms status` 6. `lsmod | grep nvidia` 7. `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and 8 `lspci -knn | grep -A 3 -E "(VGA|3D)"`

Comment: @giulio, check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1105097/822295), it may help you

Comment: Please `disable` secure boot. Nvidia will not work with `secure boot` enabled. Please reach BIOS setup screen by pressing `del` key and disable `secured boot`.

Comment: Did you use **nomodeset** in `/etc/default/grub` file? Check with this command `cat /etc/default/grub | grep -i GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Also note that **display UNCLAIMED** is there for both `intel` and `nvidia` in the output of command **sudo lshw -c video**. That is why `nvidia-smi` command is failing. BTW, what is the output of command `lsmod | grep nouveau`

Comment: Yes, I am using nomodeset. The output of the command you mentioned is literally nothing: giulio@giulio-ZenBook-UX431FN:~$ lsmod | grep nouveau
giulio@giulio-ZenBook-UX431FN:~$

Comment: @giulio did you disable `secured boot`? After disabled, run command `mokutil --sb-state` to verify that its is disabled. After installing drivers, you don't need `nomodeset`. After removing it,  you need to run `sudo update-grub` again followed by reboot. After ubuntu login, run command `nvidia-smi` and check the result.

Comment: I tried the full operation mentioned, but as I was saying, after all I get a black screen with only a white underscore sign at upper left corner after the grub and after the system tries to load

Comment: Did you install Nvidia using command line?

Comment: No, by the software updater

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93351/discussion-between-marmayogi-and-giulio).

Answer (score 0):

The driver is probably installed, but the Nvidia adapter isn't enabled.

Enable it by running:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

Then log out and log in again. The adapter should now be enabled and `nvidia-smi` should work.