# After installing Nvidia driver 430 ubuntu 19.04 does not boot and stuck on boot screen

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

Recently I bought a Nvidia GTX 1660 graphics card, and I already have windows 10 and I installed Ubuntu 19.04 alongside windows 10.

I added the graphics driver PPA and installed Nvidia drivers using the command

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-430
```

everything worked fine until I reboot and it is stuck at the boot screen as below:

[Boot screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP84X.jpg)

I did everything I could. I am sharing all of them

Try 1: I booted in recovery mode and selected the following option

```
dpkg             Repair broken packages
```

Previously a few times this solved my problem and computer booted successfully with nvidia drivers but nowdays it does not solve my problem.

Try 2: I booted in recovery mode and I opened root terminal from there and uninstalled nvidia driver using

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Then everything went fine and I successfully booted without nvidia driver and now my screen resolution reduced to 1024x768

PLEASE HELP ME TO INSTALL NVIDIA DRIVER PROPERLY. I'D BE GRATEFUL.

Comment: Check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1105097/822295)

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with: First, enable your secure boot feature in the BIOS.
Second remove and purge all your nvidia packages using:

```
apt-get purge nvidia*
```

then to remove other dependencies of the NVIDIA driver:

```
apt-get autoremove
```

Then, reboot and

```
apt-get install nvidia-driver-4xx
```

where `xx` is the version number.
At the end of installation process it will ask you to set a secure boot password, set it to something (but remember it and write it down).

Then proceed to reboot, which then you will be asked to enroll the key

- choose it then enter your password
- exit it and proceed to boot.
- Done

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of solutions of this problem. But I found the simplest solution, which is to disable secure boot. So, if anyone having the same problem, they should disable secure boot first and check.