# Fresh 20.04.2 install fails to boot after nvidia driver install

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia

I have been working on this problem now for a solid day and would really appreciate some help!

I am attempting to dual-boot Ubuntu 20.04 on an existing Windows installation. The Ubuntu install works on nouveau drivers, but upon installing nvidia-drivers-460 the boot-up hangs on the motherboard manufacturer screen. All hardware works on the Windows install so it's certainly a software problem.

**Hardware information:**

- Mobo: ASUS PRIME Z590-V
- -> Checked that BIOS is up to date
- SSD: 1TB WD Blue SN550 Series PCIe NVMe
- CPU: Intel i9-10900K 10/20
- GPU: ZOTAC GAMING GeForce RTX 3090 Trinity

**What I've done:**

- From Windows, shrunk the NVMe FAT partition and set aside 300 GB for Ubuntu,
- Disabled secure boot in BIOS
- Installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 onto freed partition from a USB flash drive,
- -> Chose option to not install graphics drivers at this point,
- Ubuntu successfully boots using nouveau drivers,
- Install updates etc. via Ethernet connection,
- Reboot, no problems. Now install nvidia-drivers-460 (recommended). Tried various approaches such as ubuntu-drivers, reinstalling the OS a few times, etc.

**The problem:**

- Grub boots successfully. But, Ubuntu cannot boot (hangs at ASUS screen) and recovery mode fails at "Reached target local encrypted volumes".
- Because I cannot even reach the recovery screen, at this point I need to reinstall the OS from the flash drive.

Picture of where recovery mode hangs attached. Any help is seriously appreciated!

[Screen output where recovery mode hangs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnfOa.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is GPU drivers in play, there is a golden boot settings : `nomodeset`

This will basically disable any hardware acceleration before the X server starts (and sometimes will disable all hardware acceleration [see this for more info](https://askubuntu.com/a/207177/1133128))

Here are the steps :

- With the selector on your main GRUB entry press <kbd>e</kbd> to enter the editor
- Find the entry that starts with linux
- Delete `quiet` `splash` (or anything you have at the end of the line, but not touching any word that starts with a `$`) from the line (don't worry the change is only going to last one boot) replacing it with `nomodeset` (the line should look like this

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.9.12-050912-generic root=UUID=<REDACTED> ro nomodeset $vt_handoff
```

- Boot using <kbd>F10</kbd> and wait to be spawned to the DE (if you don't no worry, stike <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> to enter the tty)

Then try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1087050/1133128) NOTE : Replace `gedit` with `nano`, especially if you're running [Wayland](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Wayland) (Wayland can be an horror with proprietary drivers, and GUI apps that require root privileges)

If it doesn't work make a full reinstall of the drivers (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1151782/1133128) (omit the secure boot part))

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply and information! Unfortunately, I think my problem is worse than this, as the command line can't be accessed after nomodeset from Grub (after lots of restarts too). With nomodeset, booting hangs *after* printing "Loading initial ramdisk". For example, recovery mode uses nomodeset and it won't boot either. I think the problem is related to where recovery mode fails...

Comment: Update: I have managed to access the command line using /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-45-generic root=UUID=<REDACTED> ro nomodeset noapic apci=off 3 $vt_handoff , and generate an nvidia bug report. I'll head over to the nvidia forums and see if they can help out!

Comment: Third update: I've decided it's not worth the trouble and am just going to use WSL2. Will mark as accepted answer because it was definitely on the right track, but the specific issue was beyond my abilities. :)

Comment: Fourth update: Since CUDA doesn't work well in WSL either, I've gone for a straight Ubuntu install and will now quest to get this driver issue sorted out, one way or another!