# Installing Cuda on Dell Laptop

Tags: nvidia, dell, cuda

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and want to install cuda library. But it kept failing so I deleted it all and reinstalled the Ubuntu 18.04. So how can I install cuda libraries on this? Also, when I type in nvidia-smi on the terminal window I can see the name of the GPU. Thank you!

Comment: First you should install the appropriate driver for your Nvidia card (you can get this from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1105097/822295)). Second, install Cuda by following this [tutorial](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Install-CUDA-10-together-with-9-2-on-Ubuntu-18-04-with-support-for-NVIDIA-20XX-Turing-GPUs-1236/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo ubuntu-drivers install  
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit   
sudo reboot
```

After rebooting run the following command to show what Nvidia driver version is installed:

```
apt policy nvidia-driver-390 nvidia-driver-430
```

If nvidia-driver-390 is installed run the following command:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-compute-utils-390
```

If nvidia-driver-430 is installed run the following command:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-compute-utils-430
```

Comment: Thanks! =) appreciate it