# Nvidia Driver won't install on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04

Installed driver with this command:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440
```

but when i want to check Nvidia driver, I'm getting this error:

```
$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running
```

If I look at Nvidia-settings, the window will show up, but all i can see is: Select GPU you would like to use and 3 options below, and nothing else. Here's the output:

```
$ nvidia-settings

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:7221): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:08:55.807: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 16:08:55.810: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 16:08:55.810: PRIME: is it supported? yes
** Message: 16:08:55.837: PRIME: Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|on-demand|query
** Message: 16:08:55.837: PRIME: on-demand mode: "1"
** Message: 16:08:55.837: PRIME: is "on-demand" mode supported? yes
```

in Software & Updates > Additional Drivers, I chose: Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-440 (proprietary, tested)

In Settings > About, Graphics: displays integrated Intel, instead of Nvidia 1050TI

Did everything as in
[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105090/cant-change-to-nvidia-proprietary-driver-ubuntu-18-04/1105097#1105097)  comment, :

```
$ prime-select query
nvidia
```

It says nvidia, but still nothing's working

FIXED:
I managed to fix it by disabling secure boot in BIOS

Comment: Did you reboot your PC after installing the drivers? If not, reboot then run `prime-select query` to check which GPU your PC is using.

Comment: prime-select query says it's nvidia, but nothing works

Comment: May removing the installed Nvidia driver and reinstall it again using `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` would work.. [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1105097/822295) might be helpful

Comment: `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for glx`

Comment: if @karel solved your problem, you should mark that as the answer. in my case this has nothing to do with secure boot.

Answer (score 3):

You have the correct Nvidia 440 proprietary graphics packages from the default Ubuntu 20.04 repositories installed, but the integrated Intel graphics processor is being used instead of Nvidia graphics. Disable Secure Boot in BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: Thanks!  This resolved my issue instantly and effectively. +1

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this problem with ubuntu 20.04 and nvidia driver installation. I could not do a secure boot disable as the system would not allow it. However, another solution worked for me. Given below are the steps:

1. Restart the machine and click F2 or Del to enter the Boot Set up Menu
2. In the bottom right click advanced Menu
3. Scroll down and click on Secure Boot
4. In the UEFI dropdown, change the Windows UEFI mode to other OS and leave the enhanced disabled.
   Restart the machine and try nvidia-smi and the driver should be installed and working..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well and tried several installations with apt-get of different nvidia packages without success. Finally I did go into the drivers management of Ubuntu and did an install from there. Whatever Ubuntu is doing there different, it worked for me afterwards.

Side note: After Kernel upgrade the system gets broken again, because the triggers of drivers/modules do not work well. So I first have to chose a different driver and doing its install and select the wished package again, very annoying.

The command to get this dialog is software-properties-gtk:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same Graphics and issues with install via Software Updater.
Solution was fresh new install and thick box " Instal third party software".
Now I am running through Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 630 (KBL GT2) driver.

If you just install restricted-extras without full purge, it won't work.

Let me know if you installed already " Third party software ?  I am kind of sure, it wasn't done  ;) Just let system choose the right driver.

After that, you don't need to install any other graphics driver.
For addition after successful install, you can change your mode to "Powersafe " for better energy management. You should also ensure, your Bios setup has dislable " Secure boot ". Hope it'll works.

[image]

Comment: 'Solution was fresh new install' whad do yo mean by that? Do I have to reinstall OS? And I used sudo `apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras` but it didn't help

Comment: Yes, I have to reinstall my OS.