# White screen on second monitor Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, multiple-monitors, amd-processor, dual-graphics

When I boot up Ubuntu on my dual boot laptop, the Ubuntu logo appears on both screens (connected with HDMI through Nvidia 1650) along with the HP logo, but the second I login, everything goes white on the second monitor. As I use the mouse on the primary laptop monitor, chunks flash to show the desktop underneath for mere seconds but that's it. I am usually able to see the mouse on the white screen, but when portions become visible it then defaults to show the mouse on the desktop - which is mostly covered by white. If keep it unplugged on boot and try to plugin later, no signal is sent to the monitor nor does Ubuntu recognize it. Everything works fine when I boot onto Windows. I've tried a ton of stuff already and I can't get it to work. From setting my Nvidia GPU as primary, then setting my AMD integrated as primary, to changing the resolution on the monitor, to rebooting, to fresh install. Activating TV mode, or setting the second monitor as primary only causes immense lag rendering the system unusable until reboot.

I need help resolving this. If anyone has ideas or has come across this issue before I could really use your input.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED

I had tried something similar before but in that case I used the *ubuntu-drivers devices* command to get a driver recommendation. Activating this driver did not resolve my issue, but at the time I did not try the other drivers available to me. Once I realized this, I tried the *nvidia-driver-515 (proprietary)* and it seems to be working great. My hardware includes AMD Ryzen 5 5600H with Radeon Graphics, and Nvidia 1650 GPU.

Answer (score 0):

The steps from this answer worked for my second monitor issue.
https://askubuntu.com/a/1105097
Additionally, at the end of running `sudo apt install nvidia-<driver number>` a series of dialogs will appear asking you to create a password to enroll Mok
Upon rebooting, you should see a screen with a couple options like "reboot", "Enroll Mok", etc. If you hit "reboot" your problem won't get fixed.
Hit "Enroll Mok", follow the steps and enter the password you made, then it should reboot, and your problem should be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Open `Software & Updates`, then go to the tab `Additional drivers`, wait until it will search for them automatically, then (what worked for me) I've selected the first driver in the list, then clicked on `Apply changes`, wait for downloading them, then click `Restart`. This worked for me. The problem is for sure in the computer drivers, so try other drivers from the list until it will work for you.