# Night Light not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, system-settings, night-light

Today I realized that Night Light stopped working in my machine. When I try to set it up, nothing happens. See attached gif:

[image: trying to enable night light]

I am not sure what's causing it to fail. I don't know if there are any logs generated by this tool, or if there's another way to enable Night Light.

Any idea what to try? This was working a few months ago.

When I check `/var/log/syslog`, there are some messages related to night light when I use the *«Sunset to Sunrise»* schedule, but nothing indicates that it failed:

```
Sep 19 22:46:37 sambayon gnome-control-c[22940]: no sunset data, using 16.00
Sep 19 22:46:37 sambayon gnome-control-c[22940]: no sunrise data, using 8.00
```

Comment: As a workaround, I have installed the `sct` program and using it manually, but it would be nice if I could fix *Night Light*.

Comment: I just realized that the night light wouldn't show up in a OBS recorded video. Regardless of that, there's no noticeable change in the display color temperature. What happens in the gif, is the same as what I'm seeing on the screen.

Comment: It happened to me too. I have it set to manual timing, from 05:00 to 04:59. When it broke, even the nightlight icon did not show up in the panel. But I noticed that my monitors (laptop + external HDMI) have disappeared from the _Settings_ app's _Color_ settings sidebar item. I set the preinstalled `D50` color profile for my laptop's screen on that _Color_ settings UI. But now only my printer had shown up to set a color profile to: the monitors did not. I think it's related. A reboot however restored everything: the _Color_ settings UI, the laptop screen color profile, and night light.

Comment: @Levente - you should post this as an answer as it seems to be a solution, and also so it can be voted upon.

Comment: Not only you, and not only 20.04. I just come to notice that night light is out here too! Ubuntu 21.10.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same problem in 20.04, so I tried to reinstall `gnome-control-center` and then tried to restart my computer and it works.

Try running this command in a terminal to reinstall control center:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

and then restart you computer.

Comment: `Reinstallation of gnome-control-center is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.` for me just restarting my PC solved the problem.

Comment: Worked for me (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design, driver 470.129.06). Thank you

Answer (score 7):

For me, It worked by just rebooting my system.

Answer (score 5):

For NVIDIA GPU users: I had to reinstall my NVIDIA drivers after a kernel update. You can check if your driver is working with `nvidia-smi` -- if not, you may need to install drivers.

Comment: Works for me. I've used this tutorial to make nvidia drivers works: https://linuxhint.com/install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu/ and this to enable change of it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/540862/cant-activate-proprietary-driver-for-nvidia-from-additional-drivers-ubuntu-14

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue in Ubuntu 20.10.
After turning on night light, I restart the computer and it works normally.

Answer (score 0):

Flux was conflicting with the night light program, enabling the Manual mode worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Why you don't uninstall/disable F.lux instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling MST in your Monitor's OSD if it has that option.

Multi Stream Transport allows daisy-chaining multiple monitors via display port. I have a multiple-monitor setup and recognized that on the one monitor that has this option night light wasn't working at all.